# How to assign (file.txt) tu variable via Applescript

Tags: applescript

I need to select a .txt file that contains a list of urls and pass it to **theFile** variable.
unfortunately it doesn't work, the system says it can't find the file.

on run

```
set theFile to ("Macintosh HD⁩:⁨Utenti⁩:enricosindico⁩:Scrivania:URL.txt⁩")
```

open theFile

Comment: You are assigning a **string** not a file. The parentheses are irrelevant. And *who* should open the file?

Comment: I'm trying to edit a SiteSucker script that allows you to read a URL list from a file ... I would like to automate this piece of code by selecting the file by default ...
on run

set theFile to (choose file with prompt "Select a plain text file containing a list of URLs:" of type {"txt"})

open theFile

end run